# What does 'let' mean in lambda expression for livedata observable Kotlin

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin, let

I was wondering if someone can explane me the word let in a lambda expression with livedata. Is it just to print the lamda expression? Some people use it to get no null pointer exceptions anymore i guess?

```
wordViewModel.allWords.observe(this, Observer { value -> 
    value?.let { /*DO SOMETHING WITH VALUE ('IT')*/ }
})
```

Comment: `let` is a function whose documentation you can reach using `ctrl-j`. It says "Calls the specified function block with `this` value as its argument and returns its result."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`let()` is a Kotlin "scope function". In particular, using `let()` with the safe call (`?.`) only executes the lambda supplied to `let()` if the receiver (`value`) is not `null`.

Because of the way the `Observer` interface is defined, `value` can be `null`. So, `value -> value?.let { //DO OTHER THINKS WITH 'IT' }` basically says "ignore `null`, but execute this lambda for all non-`null` values".